# Max Frequency od Azure Cognitive Search API Calls: document ingestion

Tags: c#, azure, vector, azure-cognitive-search

I have this function that calls MergeOrUpload on the IndexDocumentBatch and then IndexDocumentsAsync. I am constructing the batch with the documents as they become available, which can be rather quickly. I know there might be limitations of how frequently I can call these Azure APIs - it is somewhere in Azure documentation, but I cannot figure out how many times per second or minute can I call this function (I do know the size and quantity of documents limits)

```
public static async Task UploadDocumentsAsync(SearchClient searchClient, List<Hotel> hotels)
    {
        var batch = IndexDocumentsBatch.MergeOrUpload(hotels);
        try
        {               
            await searchClient.IndexDocumentsAsync(batch).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to index the documents: \n{0}",ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#throttling-limits), API requests are throttled as the system approaches peak capacity.
For operations related to an index, below are the limits:

- **Create Index (POST /indexes):** 12 requests per minute per search unit.
- **Create or Update Index (PUT /indexes/myindex):** 6 requests per second per search unit.
- **Delete Index (DELETE /indexes/myindex):** 12 requests per minute per search unit.

Additionally, it is recommended to implement an exponential backoff strategy for retrying failed indexing attempts.
This strategy involves incrementally increasing the delay between retry attempts in case of failure, which helps to efficiently manage the load on the service and improve the likelihood of successful indexing without hitting the rate limits.

Check this [documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/search/tutorial-optimize-indexing-push-api.md)  for more details.